# Want to use emoticon (emoji) in PHP

Tags: php, encode, utf

I want to encode `\xf0\x9f\x98\xad` to `\ud83d\ude2d` and decode back from `\ud83d\ude2d` to `\xf0\x9f\x98\xad` in PHP. Please suggest some functions.

**I want to use this for emoji.**

Actually my iPhone app gets `\ud83d\ude2d` from an API and I've stored this in my database. Now to display that emoticon in the browser I have to convert it into `\xf0\x9f\x98\xad`.

I've tried following class I got from internet.

Class file (cs.php) :

```
class Emoji
{
    /**
     * Encode emoji in text
     * @param string $text text to encode
     */
    public static function Encode($text) {
        return self::convertEmoji($text,"ENCODE");
    }

    /**
     * Decode emoji in text
     * @param string $text text to decode
     */
    public static function Decode($text) {
        return self::convertEmoji($text,"DECODE");
    }

    private static function convertEmoji($text,$op) {
        if($op=="ENCODE"){
            return preg_replace_callback('/([0-9|#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}|\x{00a9}|\x{203C}|\x{2047}|\x{2048}|\x{2049}|\x{3030}|\x{303D}|\x{2139}|\x{2122}|\x{3297}|\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?/u',array('self',"encodeEmoji"),$text);
        }else{
                        return preg_replace_callback('/(\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})+/',array('self',"decodeEmoji"),$text);
        }
    }

    private static function encodeEmoji($match) {
        return str_replace(array('[',']','"'),'',json_encode($match));
    }

    private static function decodeEmoji($text) {            
        if(!$text) return '';
        $text = $text[0];
        $decode = json_decode($text,true);
        if($decode) return $decode;
        $text = '["' . $text . '"]';
        $decode = json_decode($text);
        if(count($decode) == 1){
           return $decode[0];
        }
        return $text;
    }
}
```

My front file :

```
include "cs.php";
echo $a = Emoji::Encode("\xf0\x9f\x98\xad")."<br>"; // gives me \ud83d\ude2d
echo $b = Emoji::Decode($a); // gives me ðŸ˜­
```

When I tried to encode the characters I got perfect result which is `\ud83d\ude2d`. But when I tried to decode `\ud83d\ude2d` I got some strange characters like `ðŸ˜­`.

Comment: what's wrong with a simple str_replace? have you actually tried to code anything for this yet?

Comment: Yes I've tried. See my updated question.

Comment: What emojis are you trying to show? Font file? Images? Not really getting what that code is supposed to do (seems a bit overcomplicated) and what the expected output would be? And where iPhones API (what API) has anything to do with this?

Comment: Nothing is related with iPhone API. it's working fine. It gives me `\ud83d\ude2d` and i stored it in my database. now i want to display message coming from iPhone API in my website. For that i want to convert `\ud83d\ude2d` into  `\xf0\x9f\x98\xad` so that my browser can display smiley. See the example : http://codepad.org/Hb2E7HlO

Comment: That code just shows me wierd characters. Are the smileys in a custom font file? Is it image sprites? There aren't any "global" emojis that works in all fonts/browsers.

Comment: No there is no images. Just view this link : http://codepad.org/Hb2E7HlO.

Comment: I did.. and like I said, that codepad-snippet only gives me weird characters. No emojicon: http://prntscr.com/a0w8dq - Again, there aren't any global emoji-set that works in all broswers/character sets/OS's.

Comment: Please see my screenshot : http://prntscr.com/a0w9xu

Comment: I don't know how to say this in any other way for you to not ignore it: *there aren't any global emoji-set that works in all broswers/character sets/OS's*. It depends on your browser/character set(font)/OS.

Comment: I got your point from your first comment.Do you have other way to display iPhone unicode characters in web?

Comment: What exactly do you want to express with that notation, `\ud83d\ude2d` and `\xf0\x9f\x98\xad`? Neither of those strings taken literally will display any emoji. To display an emoji, you need to produce the binary string `0xf09f98ad` (). Is that what you're referring to? – In a nutshell, you want to convert the Unicode escape sequence notation `\ud83d\ude2d` into an actual binary string?

Comment: @deceze , Hey why you've marked as duplicate. that question don't even close to mine. They have different requirements. Please reopen this question. I still didn't get my answer.

Comment: Those answers there *seem* extremely related. At least the decoding from Unicode escape notation to strings seems to be answered there. If that's not all you need, please clarify your question a bit. Contrast how the solutions there are *not* sufficient to solve your issue and why and it'll become clearer what exactly you *do* need.

Comment: I just want to display emoji stored in my database as `\ud83d\ude2d` on my website.`\ud83d\ude2d` is coming from iphone. iOS developer has encoded an emoji in UTF8 and send it to me. But how can i display that emoji in my browser as i only have `\ud83d\ude2d` in my database.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions from the duplicate?! They work!

Comment: Yes I've tried solution as mentioned in accepted answer and it's not working.

Comment: Well, the next one is! https://3v4l.org/XH9h6

Comment: Then why its not working in my localhost.I've wrote same in localhost `json_decode('"\ud83d\ude2d"');` but it give me some strange character as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Because you're not interpreting the result as UTF-8?! [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Oh yes, that's the case. Now it's working fine.